# numpy write with two masks

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array `a` with 100 elements that I want to conditionally update. I have the first mask `m` which selects elements of `a` that will be tried to update. Out of `a[m]` (say, 50 elements), I want to update a subset some elements, but leaves others. So the second mask `m2` has `50=m.sum()` elements, only some of which are `True`.

For completeness, a minimal example:

```
a = np.random.random(size=100)
m = a > 0
m2 = np.random.random(size=m.sum()) < 0
newvalues = -np.random.randint(size=m2.sum())
```

Then if I were to do

`a[m][m2] = newvalues`

This does not change the values of a, because fancy indexing `a[m]` makes a copy here. using indices (with `where`) has the same behaviour.

Instead, this works:

```
m12 = m.copy()
m12[m] = m2

a[m12] = newvalues
```

However, this is verbose and difficult to read.

Is there a more elegant way to update a subset of a subset of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can potentially first compute the "final index" of interest and then use those indexes to update. One way to achieve this in a more "numpy" way is to mask the first index array, which is computed based on the first mask array.

```py
final_mask = np.where(m)[0][m2]
a[final_mask] = newvalues
```

Comment: Ah, nice, so I can define `def doublemask(m,m2): return np.where(m)[0][m2]` and do `a[doublemask(m,m2)] = newvalues`.

Answer (score 1):

First compute the indices of elements to update:

```
indices = np.array(range(100))
indices = indices[m1][m2]
```

then use `indices` to update array `a`:

```
a[indices] = newvalue
```